# Obtaining a nested objects using Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I'm new to Project Reactor and R2DBC. How to receive and merge `Flux<Child>` with `Mono<Parent>` properly using Spring Data R2DBC reactive repositories?

Parent:

```
@Table("parent")
public class Parent{

@Id
private Long id;
private String name;

@Transient
private Flux<Child> children;
```

ParentRepository:

```
interface ParentRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Parent, Long> {

@Query()
Mono<Parent> findOneByName(String name);
```

Child:

```
@Table("child")
public class Child{

@Id
private Long id;
```

ChildRepository:

```
interface ChildRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Child, Long> {

@Query()
Flux<Child> findAllByParentId(Long parentId);
```

ParentPersistenceAdapter:

```
public Mono<Parent> findParent(String parentName) {
    return parentRepository.findOneByName(parentName)
      //how to invoke childRepository.findAllByParentId()
      //and set this Flux to Parent's Mono

}
```

My solution is:

```
public Mono<Parent> findParent(String parentName) {
    return parentRepository.findOneByName(parentName)
      .map(parent -> {
            Flux<Child> children = childRepository.findAllByParentId(parent.getId())
            children.subscribe();
            return parent.setChildren(children );
        });      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the existence of a [`withChildren(Flux<Child> children)` type method](https://projectlombok.org/features/With), you can just do:

```
parentRepository.findById(parentId)
    .map(p -> p.withChildren(childRepository.findAllByParentId(parentId)));
```

However, this is a bit odd - you wouldn't usually have a `Flux` on a DAO like that as you'd need to subscribe to it and manage the content separately. You'd more normally have a `List<Child>` instead. For that situation, you can collect the child stream as a list, `zip()` the corresponding `Mono` publishers together, then combine them into your final `Parent` object.

So assuming a `withChildren(List<Child> children)` method:

```
Mono.zip(parentRepository.findById(parentId),
    childRepository.findAllByParentId(parentId).collectList(),
    (t1,t2) -> t1.withChildren(t2));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. If just copy `Flux<Child>`, then `childRepository.findAllByParentId(parentId)` is not executed, because I need to subscribe to this `Flux<Role>`. How to do this using Project Reactor operators?

Comment: But I want to make application fully reactive, then I need to use `Flux` instead of using collections, right?

Comment: @KirillValyushko No, that makes no sense. `Flux` is a stream of data, it's not a replacement for using collections. Being fully reactive is about being non-blocking (and `collectList()` is non-blocking, since it provides a `Mono<List>`). You may wish to do some reading around reactor and reactive programming in general, otherwise you're likely to come increasingly unstuck.

Comment: @MichaelBerry how can we achieve this in case when `parentRepository` return `Flux<Parent>` ? execute __N__ times `childRepository.findAllByParentId(parentId)` for each Parent object found in database ?

Comment: @MichaelBerry and how should it look if I want to retrieve all `parent` elements with children without calling `findAllByParentId` for each parent? Is it possible?

edit: sorry, I haven't notice that @HalayemAnis asked the same question.. but maybe worth pinging you again :)

Comment: In regards with the non-blocking nature of r2dbc, the infamous N+1 problem is related in any way with using for each item 2 trips to the database here?